# Tokio Tasks losing their Wakers

Tags: rust, concurrency, rust-tokio

[image]

As you can see I have a lot of tasks losing their Wakers,
However, I can't seem to understand why or how thats possible

Where task gets spawned:

```
loop {
    tokio::select! {
        // send final bundle
        Some(bundle) = bundle_receiver.recv() => {
            for client in &clients {
                tokio::spawn(
                    send_bundle(bundle.clone(), client.clone())
                );
            }
        },
     }
 }
```

The Function:

```
pub async fn send_bundle(
    bundle: BundleRequest,
    client: Arc<SignerMiddleware<FlashbotsMiddleware<Arc<Provider<Http>>, Wallet<SigningKey>>, Wallet<SigningKey>>>,
) {

    match client.inner().send_bundle(&bundle).await {
        Ok(info) => {
            
            debug!("\nBundle Hash: {:?}\nRelay: {:?}", info.bundle_hash, client.inner().relay());

        },
        Err(info) => {

            trace!("\nResponse: {:?}\nRelay: {:?}", info, client.inner().relay());
     
        }
    }
}
```

basically it spawns a task to make an API call, as simple as that

This is a very new concept to me,
I had no solutions or possible fixes for it,
I tried to add .awaits, or returns, but none of them seems to remove this warning

Comment: @Filburt edited

Comment: What does `.send_bundle()` return? If its your type please show the code, if not please link to the crate/documentation for it. Since that is the only thing being `.await`-ed in your `async` function, the responsibility for the waker can't go anywhere else.

Comment: @kmdreko document [send_bundle](https://docs.rs/ethers-flashbots/0.13.1/src/ethers_flashbots/middleware.rs.html#180-207)

it returns some information and another future that can be .await ed (but it is unnecessary for my use-case),
however, I tried to .await that returned future to see if it would fix the waker issue, which it didn't

Comment: Just to cover our bases, does you code work? (and you are just curious about these warnings) or does it not work and that's why you are looking into issues?

Comment: well, the porgram seems to be working,
sometimes the load goes heavier than expected and I thought this might be issue that's causing the problem

Comment: It seems possible that these waker threads are crashing. Have you checked whether any additional errors are being logged?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect, that `client.inner().send_bundle(&bundle).await` doesn't have a timeout or something blocks it. The problem appears that the call hangs the task out. I would propose to use tokio timeout and see what happens:

```rust
use tokio::time::timeout;
use std::time::Duration;

// ...

let result = timeout(Duration::from_secs(5), client.inner().send_bundle(&bundle)).await;

match result {
    Ok(response) => {
        // Handle the response
    }
    Err(_) => {
        // Handle the timeout error
    }
}
```

https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/time/fn.timeout.html